# Google App Engine: Python: WebOb: How to get POST data in JSON format?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, webapp2, webob

I am building a web app on the Google App Engine platform, which uses webapp2, which uses WebOb. I would like to `POST` some data in JSON format, including nested arrays and dictionaries. E.g.:

```
$.post('/addvendor', {'vendor': {'name': 'test', 'description': 'a good company', 'tags':['foo', 'bar']}}, function(data){console.log(data)}, 'application/json')
```

However, on the server side, the data comes in as a flat "MultiDict" object, not anything like the original nested JSON object that I `POST`ed. E.g.:

```
>>> print self.request.params.items()
[(u'vendor[name]', u'test'), (u'vendor[description]', u'a good company'), (u'vendor[tags][]', u'foo'), (u'vendor[tags][]', u'bar')]
```

This object is very difficult to parse. In my server code, is there a way to get the same data in standard JSON format, or at least a Python equivalent using nested dictionaries and arrays, on the server so that I can manipulate and examine the data easily?

Comment: I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058233/how-to-convert-a-multidict-to-nested-dictionary

Unfortunately the answer to that question is unhelpful to me because I can't include the formencode package in a google app engine environment. I think I may switch over to Heroku instead and use node.js.

Comment: $.post is jquery? you are using python 2.7.*? Can you then not do something like: `vendor = json.loads(self.request.get('vendor'))` You have to import json with `import json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(updated with jayhendren's help) You should use $.ajax and manually set contentType='application/json; charset=utf-8' instead because $.post uses default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" content type. Also you need to manually encode data to JSON-string with JSON.stringify:

```
$.ajax({url:'/addvendor', 
        type: 'post', 
        data:JSON.stringify({'vendor': {'name': 'test', 'description': 'a good company', 'tags':['foo', 'bar']}}), 
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){console.log(data)}})

...

print json.loads(self.request.body)
```

Comment: This answer, I think, shows a lack of understanding of the webob interface. Here is the value of `self.request.body`: `vendor%5Bname%5D=test&vendor%5Bdescription%5D=a+good+company&vendor%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=foo&vendor%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=bar` And here is what happens if I try to decode that as a json oject: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Sorry, forgot about one important thing: jquery.ajax's data param must  be plain object or string (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you pass just object, jquery converts it to query string which you are seeing. To send JSON-encoded data you should manually build JSON-string by using JSON.stringify()

Comment: Huh, thanks, this is starting to get there. I still get a `no JSON object could be decoded` error, but at least I have an encoded string that represents a JSON object rather than a multi-dict to work with. That's much better than passing a straight JSON object to `$.post`. However, I've used other APIs which didn't require me to `stringify` the JSON object before `POST`ing it to the server. For instance, when using backbone.js, I could interpret the `POST`ed data on the as a JSON object on the server without requiring that the client `stringify` it or that the server decode it.

Comment: You still get this error using self.request.body? I suppose jquery doesn't encode to JSON automatically because it is wide-purpose library and it is developer who decides how to send data to server. If my answer were useful please accept it)

Comment: Here is the value of `self.request.body`: `%7B%22vendor%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22a+good+company%22%2C%22tags%22%3A%5B%22foo%22%2C%22bar%22%5D%7D%7D=`. As you can see, it needs to be decoded. ;) I think the urllib library will help with that. However, the data being passed in is, inexplicably, being interpreted as a key (with no associated value), hence the `=` at the end.

Comment: Finally, I got it. On the client side: `$.ajax({url:'/addvendor', type: 'post', data:JSON.stringify({'vendor': {'name': 'test', 'description': 'a good company', 'tags':['foo', 'bar']}}), success:function(data){console.log(data)}, contentType:'application/json', processData: false})` On the server side: `json.loads(self.request.body)`. This works, though I'm mildly irritated that I have to `JSON.stringify` the object and make sure that the request contains `processData: false`. I guess I'll just wrap the ajax call in a function on the client side and call the wrapper instead :)

Comment: Sorry again, you should use $.ajax instead and set contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8' manually ($.post is just wrapper for $.ajax which uses default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" content type). Didn't mention before because $.post works fine for me too and doesn't urlencodes post data )

Comment: OOps, you've already got it) If you don't mind, I'll correct my answer anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's going on exactly - `$.post` in a different environment (another project I am working on) seems to behave more like the `$.ajax` call I mentioned earlier. If you edit your answer so it matches what I have found to work, then I'll accept it. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Aren't sure, but maybe issue is in different jquery versions? Very strange that you have to set processData: false, because jquery should process anything but strings o_O. Updated answer, and thank you too!

Comment: Possibly. I don't know what jQuery version the other project is using. A few other developers have worked on it as well, so it is possible that the jQuery library may have been modified or that the $.post function may have been overloaded somewhere upstream.

Answer (score 1):

use json.dumps(yourdata)
don't forgot to change the header Content-Type to application/json

```
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
session.post(<url>, data=json.dumps(yourdata))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think you read carefully the question or the other answer. I don't need to send a POST request from the server, I need to send it using a javascript AJAX call from the client. Furthermore, this question has already been solved, as you can see from the other answer, which I accepted, and the thread of comments.

Comment: @jayhendren +1 because it's important to understand, for webapp2/GAE, that `request.body` only works for JSON when `request.content_type == 'application/json'`. I made a change today in my tests and all of a sudden, inside the handler, my `request.body` was URL-encoded. I just had to add `content-type = application/json` on the POST and everything was back to normal.