# How to pass a list value to a webapp2 backend via $.post?

Tags: google-app-engine, coffeescript, webapp2

In my coffeescript frontend I attempt to pass a list of value to the backend

```
data = {
  id: [2, 3, 4]
}

$.post url, data
```

In the handler in a Google app engine (python) backend, I read the value like so:

```
    id_value = self.request.get('id')

    LOG.info("%s", id_value)
```

It always print out '2' only.

How can I get the backend to obtain the list `[2,3,4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post` by default sends data in url-encoded format, which handles nested structures in its own way.

You might need to encode the data in JSON before sending and then decode it on the server side - an example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205604/google-app-engine-python-webob-how-to-get-post-data-in-json-format).

Answer (score 0):

> The request object provides a get() method that returns values for arguments parsed from the query and from POST data.
>
> If the argument appears more than once in a request, by default get()
> returns the first occurrence. To get all occurrences of an argument
> that might appear more than once as a list (possibly empty), give
> get() the argument allow_multiple=True.

Hence you should use something like the below snippet. You can find more details [here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html).

```
id_value = self.request.get('id', allow_multiple=True)
```

If you need to access variables url encoded in the body of a request (generally a POST form submitted using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type), you should use something like this.

```
id_value = self.request.POST.getall('id')
```