# Flask and WTforms: how to retrieve the data from an updated pre-filled ListField of FormFields

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-wtforms

**UPDATE**

*After extra digging regarding my problem exposed below, I believe my difficulty in retrieving the data from a ListField of FormFields comes from the fact that I fail to validate the form. When I use form.validate_on_submit() instead of form.is_submitted() in the foundItem route I get the error message: TypeError: argument of type 'CSRFTokenField' is not iterable. Reading the documentation did not help me. If I don't validate the form, then I get the full html input tag from the FormField instead of the data.*

--

I am trying to write a small inventory web application to learn about **flask** and **MongoDB**. So far I am just trying to implement the basic functionalities (create, update, delete). As a starting point my database contains only items with a part number and a quantity. I manage to add new documents to the database and I can retrieve a list of documents matching a part number. Each retrieved document is used to pre-fill a **SearchedItemForm** and this form is appended to a **listField** of a form **SearchedItemListForm**. This is done to be able to update the quantity of one or more elements at the same time in the same view. So far I have failed to implement the update and would appreciate any help. Here is the code and the logic.

The forms:

```
class SearchedItemForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
        Generic form for a single item returned from a search
        in the searchItem page.

    Note:
        This class forms the building block of the class SearchedItemListForm. 
    '''
    id_ = StringField('id', validators=[DataRequired()])
    part_number = StringField('Part number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity',validators=[DataRequired()])


class SearchedItemListForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
        Form consisting of a list of SearchItemForm. This is the form
        that is passed to the searchItem page to display the found
        items.
    '''
    items = FieldList(FormField(SearchedItemForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

The search is done from the searchItem route:

```
@app.route('/item/search', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def searchItem():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        query = {form.searchField.data:form.searchValue.data}
        return redirect(url_for('foundItem', query=query))

    return render_template('searchItem.html', title='Search item',
                           form=form)
```

From the search form I get a search field and a search value and a query is produced which is passed to the foundItem route.

```
@app.route('/item/result', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def foundItem():
    query = json.loads(request.args.get('query').replace("'", "\""))
    form, pnList = listOfSearchedItems(query)

    if form.is_submitted():
        for item in form.items:
            print(item.quantity.data)
            # some code to update db

    return render_template('foundItem.html', title='Search result',
                           form=form, pnList=pnList)
```

The query is passed to the function **listOfSearchedItems** and a form of type **SearchedItemListForm** is pre-filled and returned together with a list of part numbers. Those parameters are passed to the **foundItem** template where they are shown and the quantity of any element can be changed. My difficulty is with the submission of the form. First of all, if I use if form.validate_on_submit() I get an error message TypeError: argument of type 'CSRFTokenField' is not iterable. Clearly there is something I don't understand with CSRF protection. More importantly I cannot get the quantity values as print(item.quantity.data) print the full html input tag instead of the quantity itself and this is where I would appreciate some help.

To be complete:

```
def listOfSearchedItems(query):
    '''
        return list of queried items from initial search
        in the searchItem view.

    Args:
        query(dict): dictionnary for the query

    Returns:
        items(SearchedItemForm): form containing returned items
        pnList: list of part numbers of returned items
    '''
    items = SearchedItemListForm()
    pnList = []

    results = mongo.db.optics.find(query)

    for result in results:
        item = SearchedItemForm()
        item.id_.data = str(result['_id'])
        item.part_number.data = result['part_number']
        item.quantity.data = result['quantity']
        pnList.append(result['part_number'])
        items.items.append_entry(item)

    return items, pnList
```

and the foundItem template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% if form.items %}
    {% set pnList_id=0 %}
    <form action="" method="post">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Part number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
          </tr>
          {% for item in form.items %}
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">{{ pnList[pnList_id] }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ item.quantity.data }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% set pnList_id=pnList_id+1 %}
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
      {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer here: [filling-wtforms-formfield-fieldlist-with-data-results-in-html-in-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514798/filling-wtforms-formfield-fieldlist-with-data-results-in-html-in-fields).

The append_entry function of a ListField expects data and not a Form, which was my mistake. Passing a dictionary with the proper keys/values works.