# WTForms Editable Table 'CSRFTokenField' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024273/render-html-table-with-editable-wtforms-fieldlist-and-non-editable-values-using) to create an editable table form to display data/edit from my database. I don't understand why the submit button is inside the row form class, so I put it in the table form class.

I keep getting `TypeError: argument of type 'CSRFTokenField' is not iterable`, which I suspect has something to do with using a FieldList, but I'm stuck. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629733/wtforms-editable-table-csrftokenfield-is-not-iterable), but it was never answered.

I am using the flask blueprint structure.

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField, SelectField, BooleanField, FloatField

class RowForm(FlaskForm):
    col1 = SelectField('col1',
                       choices=[(0, 'YES'), (1, 'NO')])
    col2 = FloatField('col2')
    col3 = StringField('col3')


class TableForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title')
    rows = FieldList(FormField(RowForm))

    submit = SubmitField('submit')
```

**views.py**

```
#...imports

@test.route('/table_test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_test_table():
    table_form = TableForm()
    row_static_list = RowTest.query.all()

    # looping through query to prepopulate values for editable fields
    for row in row_static_list:
        row_form = RowForm()

        # adding editable fields to Row Form
        row_form.col1 = 1 if row.col1 else 0
        row_form.col2 = row.col2
        row_form.col3 = row.col3

        table_form.rows.append_entry(row_form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(table_form.csrf_token)
        # if form is valid, update SensorConfig with changes
        if table_form.validate_on_submit():
            print('***************\nFORM IS VALID\n***************')
        else:
            print('***************\nFORM IS NOT VALID\n***************')

    return render_template('test/table_form.html', table_form=table_form, rows_fixed=row_static_list)
```

**table_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}TESTING TABLE{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dropdown.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Testing Table Form</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <form action method="post" name="TableForm">
        {{ table_form.csrf_token }}
        {{ table_form.submit }}
        <div>
            <table class="content-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col 1</th>
                        <th>Col 2</th>
                        <th>Col 3</th>
                        <th>Col 4</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for r, r_fixed in zip(table_form.rows, rows_fixed) %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ r.col1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ r.col2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ r.col3 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ r_fixed.col4 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**NOTE:** The `zip` above is required else the fixed values load as blank. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024273/render-html-table-with-editable-wtforms-fieldlist-and-non-editable-values-using).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoutout to taylor_prime and dnswrsrx on the r/Flask Discord for the help. The solution is to use Form as the Base Class for `RowForm` and FlaskForm as the Base Class for `TableForm`. Using FlaskForm as the Base Class for `RowForm` seemed to add a new csrf_token for each new instance of `RowForm` added to `FlaskForm`.

Adjusting **forms.py** to the below fixed the problem.

```
from flask_wtf import Form, FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField, SelectField, BooleanField, FloatField

class RowForm(Form):
    col1 = SelectField('col1',
                       choices=[(0, 'YES'), (1, 'NO')])
    col2 = FloatField('col2')
    col3 = StringField('col3')


class TableForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title')
    rows = FieldList(FormField(RowForm))

    submit = SubmitField('submit')
```